# Google Workspace alert or API to be notified when users are about to reach full storage

Tags: google-drive-api, gmail-api, google-workspace

I do not see anymore in Google Workspace interface a way to receive alerts when users are about to reach their storage limit (only end users receive alerts). is there any setting I can use to receive this alerts as an Administrator or any API that will let me do that?

Answer (score 1):

I have been reviewing the documentation for alerts and also storage settings in the Admin console. It seems like as Administrator you can only see the list of users and filter out of storage users.

You can view [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/12003082) Help Center for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately a setting like that is not available at the moment. It would be a great idea to share the feedback for something like that in the future. If you have a Google Workspace account you should be able to request access to the feature ideas portal and send the feedback

You can give your feedback or request a feature over here:

- https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Feature-Ideas/cmp-p/grouphub%3Aworkspace-ideas-group

Utilizing API or App script can help you to manually make a call and pull some of the data of the users and their storage, for example:

```
function getStorage() {
  var about = Drive.About.get(); 
  about.quotaBytesByService.forEach(function (s) {console.log(s)});
}
```

It should give you the usage of Drive Storage in all services that take space. You can also utilize the Reports API, to gather used quota in percentage of the users quota storage using the "used_quota_in_percentage" as suggested by the documentation. You can test it [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/userUsageReport/get)

You can add the parameter from the screenshot for all users or specific users and try to filter it in case you are looking to implement it in the future:

[image]